# Error trying to install PHPUnit from PEAR

Tags: php, pear, phpunit

```
$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony-project.com
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "channel://pear.symfony-project.com/YAML" (version >= 1.0.2)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

What do I need to do to be able to install PHPUnit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you registered the channel required to install YAML?

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

Depending on how pear is installed and configured, you may need to preface the command with "sudo" to run it as root.

From the [PHPUnit manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html):

> The PEAR channel (pear.phpunit.de)
>   that is used to distribute PHPUnit
>   needs to be registered with the local
>   PEAR environment. Furthermore, a
>   component that PHPUnit depends upon is
>   hosted on the Symfony Components PEAR
>   channel (pear.symfony-project.com).

Comment: that didn't work for me, this was the message: pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
Discovering channel pear.symfony-project.com over http:// failed with message: channel-add: temp_dir is not writable: "/usr/local/temp" - You can change this location with "pear config-set temp_dir"
Trying to discover channel pear.symfony-project.com over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.symfony-project.com" failed (channel-add: temp_dir is not writable: "/usr/local/temp" - You can change this location with "pear config-set temp_dir")

Comment: nevermind, it worked when I prepended with "sudo"

Comment: superuser.com may not be the best place to ask question regards sf2 and since there isn't yet any efficient way to receive support with symfony 2 I think the following proposal is a very good idea! - [A new Q&A site for symfony2](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36634/symfony2) - Please join & spread the word!

Answer (score 1):

If this does not work for you:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

Try this:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.de
```

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer dependant on the `pear.symfony-project.com` channel, you need to add the `pear.symfony.com` channel instead. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536668/how-do-i-correctly-install-phpunit-with-pear)

Answer (score 0):

Following solutions works for me.

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install pear.symfony.com/Yaml
sudo pear upgrade-all
pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Note: Windows user's don't use **sudo** before the command.